# How to delate rows with specific value in several txt files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, row, txt

This is a part of my code:

```py
labels = ['a','b','c',"d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","w","x","y","z"] # lista de etiquetas

fl = open(f+"/Tabla_"+Names[i]+"_"+f+".dat", "w")
fl.write("idxs " "Flujos " "n_pix \n")

for M in range(len(idxs)):
    fl.write(" {} {} {}\n".format(labels[M], Flux_Lines[M], PX[M]))

fl.close()

txts=sorted(glob.glob(f+"/Tabla_*.dat"))

for TXT in txts:
    df = pd.read_csv(TXT, sep=" ", header = None, skiprows = 1)
    f_c2 = float(df[df.columns[2]])
    d_txt = f_c2 > 0
    print(d_txt)
```

I have several txt files with this format:

```
idxs Flujos n_pix
a 0.14610920325775417 25  
b 7.749977963857448 88  
c 0.4770103911455863 31  
d 0.04608552769154015 19  
e 0.10887099144089642 23  
f 411.3453337879555 535  
g 0.19422567525896847 29  
h 0.012012563331850717 9  
i 0.0 23  
j 0.08226740119487924 14
```

There is a "0.0" value in i row and I need to delete the same row i for my other files. And then, since i row doesn't exist, "j" row has to convert in "i" row. I'm working with for weeks but I have not result, so I really appreciate if you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you removing rows that have `0.0` in the `Flujos` column in all your files or are you removing rows that have `0.0` and `23` in both the `Flujos` and `n_pix`?

Comment: Yes, only rows incluiding idxs, flujos and n_pix

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Your reply did not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could split it into a list of new lines, check if they have “0.0” then a space, and if it does, remove it from the list.

```
textfile = oldTextfile.split("\n")
editedTextfile = textfile
for item in textfile:
    if item.find("0.0 "):
        editedTextfile.pop(item)
textfile = editedTextfile
```

To go through all of the text files add a for loop that iterates around all the code I just mentioned.

Comment: This code block contains extra characters (e.g. `*` around `textfile`) and invalid "smart" quotes instead of regular quotes. Please [edit] it to make it valid Python.